# Code doesn't get played on restart? (Android)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, restart

so i made a endless runner on android(i know original right? hmmm..) And everything works fine at first. However when i die and press the restart button with the following code:

```html
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

The game stops generating rooms? Any idea why? This is my generating rooms code:

```html
    void AddRoom(float farhtestRoomEndX) {
        //pick a random room from the array and instantiate it.
        int randomRoom = Random.Range(0, AllRooms.Length);
        GameObject room = (GameObject)Instantiate(AllRooms[randomRoom]);
 
        //Find the floor, and pos to instantiate(half of the screen) and add it to active rooms.
        float roomWidth = room.transform.FindChild("Floor").localScale.x;
        float roomCenter = farhtestRoomEndX + roomWidth * 0.5f;
        room.transform.position = new Vector3(roomCenter, 0, 0);
        ActiveRooms.Add(room);
    }
 
    void GenerateRoomIfRequired() {
        //Create a new list with rooms to be deleted, and make a bool to check if rooms need to be added
        List<GameObject> DeleteRooms = new List<GameObject>();
        bool AddRooms = true;
 
        //Save the playerPos, , calculate the point after when the room needs to be removed and calculate the starting pos for instantiating a new room
        float playerX = transform.position.x;
        float removeRoomX = playerX - screenWidthInPoints;
        float addRoomX = playerX + screenWidthInPoints;
 
        //store the point where the room ens, this is used to instantiate a new room aswell
        float farthestRoomEndX = 0;
 
       // use the floor to get the room width and calculate the roomStartX and roomEndX
        foreach (var room in ActiveRooms) {
            float roomWidth = room.transform.FindChild("Floor").localScale.x;
            float roomStartX = room.transform.position.x - (roomWidth * 0.5f);
            float roomEndX = roomStartX + roomWidth;
 
            //If there is a room that starts after addRoomX, delete it. or ends to the left of removeRoomX, delete it
            if (roomStartX > addRoomX)
                AddRooms = false;
 
            if (roomEndX < removeRoomX)
                DeleteRooms.Add(room);
 
            //the most right point of the level.
            farthestRoomEndX = Mathf.Max(farthestRoomEndX, roomEndX -0.01f);
        }
 
        //remove rooms that are marked as removal, and if addRooms is still true, add a new room
        foreach (var room in DeleteRooms) {
            ActiveRooms.Remove(room);
            Destroy(room);
        }
 
        if (AddRooms)
            AddRoom(farthestRoomEndX);
    }
```

The weird part is everything runs great the first time. (The code above is beeing called from a fixedupdate.)

Comment: Might be a good idea to post some more relevant code, such as from your fixedupdate. As you say the code works fine the first time, so the issue may be elsewhere to what you have posted. Have you tried debugging the issue and seeing where it might be going wrong?

Comment: Posting my fixedupdate wont matter, all it does is call these 2 functions. as following: GenerateRoomIfRequired(); I noticed it does get into the GenerateRoom function the second time, just not towards the end. I'm debugging as we speak to find where it stops. But bit hard to debug on the phone.

Comment: EDIT: So i found it the second time it doesnt get passed the following line:            float roomWidth = room.transform.FindChild("Floor").localScale.x;

Comment: Another Edit, Im sorry for triple post, cant edit older posts... it appears to never get into the void Addroom the second time?

Comment: What does restart button call?

Comment: The restart button calls a simple scene restart. (stated above) SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex); I found out this also happens when i build it for PC. so something acts different in the actual APK. if i build it to a PC the same thing happens, but in the editor it works fine